# Why dp are different in same size phones

Tags: android

Given the picture in [android devices resolution](https://material.io/resources/devices/) info :

[image: https://material.io/resources/devices/]

Google pixel and HTC One M9 have the same `px` resolution and screen size, but they have different `dp` "resolution".

From my understanding, since they have same resolution and screen size, so their `dpi` should be the same, and thus have same `dp` "resolution"?

In order word, why they have different density in the last column. `dpi` =  `sqaure(width_px^2 + height_px^2) / inch_size`, shouldn't they be the same?

There is a same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148300/why-2-devices-of-same-size-same-resolution-claims-different-density), but no precise conclusion

Comment: Can you link where this data came from?

Comment: https://material.io/resources/devices/

Comment: @Tim Castelijns the duplicated question didn't provide a solid answer

Comment: so what. The question is literally exactly the same